# DB2 Connectivity issue in azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, db2

I'm trying to connect to DB2 server in azure http trigger function app, but getting the following error:
ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "10.xxx.xx.xxx".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you follow the documented suggestions for code "10061" (connection refused) , search for that code on this page https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql28000-sql33999#sql30081n and verify each of its suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, this issue is fixed if added port number in the connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by correcting the database Connection String so that it includes the PORT number on which the Db2-server is listening for connections.

To get suggestions for handling the specific error subcode "10061" for SQL30081N, please refer to this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql28000-sql33999#sql30081n)  and search there for "10061".

This is always a configuration error.

Comment: That error is resolved, but now new error coming as:
ERROR [08004] [IBM] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "DATABASE         " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004

Comment: It means you have an incorrect database name in your connection string, or the wrong hostname/port-number. Do not use comments to ask new questions, that is an abuse of stackoverflow.